# How to run mocha tests and node in a single npm test command ? (CI)

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, circleci

I want to use [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/) to integrate a git project.

I'm using `mocha` for my tests .

#### What i want to do?

When running `npm test` I want:

- my node server to start
- my test file to run

How can I run a single `npm test` command to run both node and my mocha tests which are already wrapped in a single `index.js` file.

I have tried this in my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node server/app.js & mocha server/tests/index.js",
    "start": "node server/app.js",
    "postinstall": "bower install"
   }
```

#### The problems with the above

- My server takes some time to start and the tests fail since they run before the server starts

Is there a standard way to run a server and the tests with a single command but I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible at all in your case I'd suggest using something like [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to do the testing. This way, you can avoid having to start a server before starting the test.

I understand that there are scenarios where using `supertest` is not possible. In such case, you could poll your server in a `before` hook before all tests to wait until it is ready:

```
before(function (done) {
  // Set a reasonable timeout for this hook.
  this.timeout(5000);

  function check() {
    if (serverIsReady()) {
      done();
      return; 
    }

    // The server is no ready, check again in 1/10th of a second.
    setTimeout(check, 100);
  }

  check(); // Start checking.
});
```

I'm not sure what `serverIsReady` should be precisely in your case. It could be an attempt at getting a trivial path from your server like issuing a `GET` on the path `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is to run your node server in your test, rather than trying to initialise it in another process.

Your mocha test should start with a require to your app, then each 
of your tests can interact with it.

For example:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.end('Hello World\n');
})

server.listen(8888);

describe('http', function(){
  it('should provide an example', function(done){
    http.get({ path: '/', port: 8888 }, function(res){
      expect(res).to.have.property('statusCode', 200);
      done();
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: how should it be done if the code is just a script not  apis.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when running a test that needs certain pre-requisites is use mochas beforeEach() functionality.

From the documentation

> You may also pick any file and add “root”-level hooks. For example,       add beforeEach() outside of all describe() blocks. This will cause the callback to beforeEach() to run before any test case, regardless of the file it lives in (this is because Mocha has an implied describe() block, called the “root suite”).

```
beforeEach(function() {
  console.log('before every test in every file');
});
```

In the before each code block you can run your command to start the server 
using for example the exec library from npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec

This will ensure your server is running before your tests are run allowing you to simply run npm test.